# Как запретить перетаскивание на себя wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-n-drop

Вот мой код:

```
private void PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Button button = sender as Button;
            if (button != null && button.Content != null)
            {
                DragDrop.DoDragDrop(button, button.Content, DragDropEffects.All);

                button.Content = null;
            }
        }
        private void Button_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            Button button = sender as Button;
            if (button != null)
            {
                button.Content = e.Data.GetData(typeof(Image));
            }
        }
```

Т.е у меня есть UniformGrid из кнопок, нужно перенести изображение из одной кнопки в другую, всё работает, если перетащить изображение из одной кнопки в другую. Однако, если нажать на изображение оно пропадёт. Подскажите как правильно это реализовать.
По сути мне просто нужно удалить изображение после перетаскивания.

Comment: `если нажать на изображение оно пропадёт` ... `button.Content = null;` ?

Comment: @tym32167 если этого не сделать  button.Content = null; то картинка перетаскивается, но ее нельзя перетащить обратно.